How can we justify why $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + \frac 1 2 \mathbb{E}[X]$ here?
I was wondering what the formal justification is behind the following reasoning:

Lemma On average a fair coin needs to be tossed two times before a "heads" is seen.
Proof. Let $E$ be the expected number of tosses before a heads is seen. We certainly need at least one toss, and if it's heads, we're done. If it's tails (which occurs with probability $1 / 2$ ), we need to repeat. Hence $E=1+\frac{1}{2} E$, which works out to $E=2$.

I tried to justify this formally using how $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$ where $X$ was the number of coin flips until we saw heads, and $Y$ was whether the first flip was a heads, but this just got me the unhelpful $\mathbb{E}[X]=p + \mathbb{E}[X] - p$. So how can we formally justify the reasoning presented here?

This is routine (if you ignore the problem of existence).  The first toss either yields Heads or it restarts the game.  Thus $E=\frac 12\times 1 +\frac 12\times (1+E)=1 +\frac 12\times E$.  See, e.g. this

The problem is if the expected value is infinite, this approach doesn't work. So you have to convince yourself that the expected value is finite.

@ThomasAndrews  The formula is still true if $E=\infty$, but your point stands.  All of this assumes that $E$ exists.  In this case, this comes down to the usual sort of geometric series.

Sure, the equation works for $\infty,$ but the step where you solve the equation for $E$ does not. @lulu

It is easy to see that $\mathbb E \left [X \right ] = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {2^n} = 2 < \infty.$

@PrincessMia  For absolutely convergent series, like $\sum n2^{-n}$, the usual arithmetic operations work just as you'd expect them to.

The law of total expectation can in fact be used to arrive at $E = 1 + \frac12 E$. Arriving at $\mathbb{E}[X]=p + \mathbb{E}[X] - p$ indicates some kind of mistake along the way.

@MishaLavrov would you have $X$ and $Y$ be the same random variables as I have given them  in my question when I described my attempt to use the law of total expectation?

@PrincessMia Yes. (To give an algebraic expression for $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ as a function of $Y$, you might want to make $Y$ an indicator random variable: say, $1$ if the coin lands heads and $0$ if the coin lands tails. But this is not necessary if you're fine with a piecewise definition of $\mathbb E[X|Y]$: one value when $Y$ is heads and another value when $Y$ is tails.)

@MishaLavrov I was able to derive $1 \over p$ using the law of total expectation with $X$ and $Y$ defined as in my question- but the expression didn't immediately resemble the $1+ \frac 1 2 \mathbb{E}[X]$. Is there a way too define $X$ and $Y$ so that using thew law of total expectation mirrors the expression $1+ \frac 1 2 \mathbb{E}[X]$; that is, applying it produces this expression in a direct manner??

The comments basically answered this, so I will just be expanding on it with an algebraic approach.
Let us call the probability of getting heads $p_H$ we then get that the expected value of the first heads we see, from the definition of expected value, is:
$$ E = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n p_H (1-p_H)^{n-1}$$
We can take out the first term and a factor of $1-p_H$ from the sum to get:
$$ E = p_H + (1-p_H)\sum_{n=2}^\infty n p_H (1-p_H)^{n-2}$$
Letting $m =n-1$ and re-indexing the sum we get:
$$ E=  p_H + (1-p_H)\sum_{m=1}^\infty (m+1) p_H (1-p_H)^{m-1}$$
Splitting the sum into 2 parts we get:
$$ E=  p_H + (1-p_H) \left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty m p_H (1-p_H)^{m-1} + \sum_{m=1}^\infty p_H (1-p_H)^{m-1}  \right) $$
Note the second term is our original definition of $E$ and the third term is a geometric series that sums to 1. Simplifying this we get
$$ E = p_H + (1-p_H)(E+1)$$
This matches with what the comments pointed out in a more intuitive way.

+1 for writing it all out, though I would say this was less intuitive than the other means.  More rigorous though.

You could write this using the probabilities and number of tosses as $$E=\frac1{2^1} \times 1 + \frac1{2^2}\times 2+ \frac1{2^3}\times 3+ \frac1{2^4}\times 4+\cdots$$ which converges and so can be rewritten by extracting $1$ from each term as  $$E=\left(\frac1{2^1} \times 1 + \frac1{2^2}\times 1+ \frac1{2^3}\times 1+ \frac1{2^4}\times 1+\cdots\right) \\+ \left(\frac1{2^2}\times 1+ \frac1{2^3}\times 2+ \frac1{2^4}\times 3+\cdots\right)$$ and then as $$E=1 + \frac12\left(\frac1{2^1}\times 1+ \frac1{2^2}\times 2+ \frac1{2^3}\times 3+\cdots\right)$$ which is $$E=1 + \frac12E.$$

Alternatively, you could use the memorylessness of $X$; if you have not tossed a head in $n$ tosses, then the distribution of the additional tosses you need is equal to the original distribution of tosses needed.  This tells you that $P(X=x+n \mid X>n) = P(X=x)$ and so  $E[X \mid X>n] = E[X]+n$.
So the law of total expectation gives $$E[X]=P(X=1)E[X \mid X=1]+P(X>1)E[X \mid X>1]$$ and applying memorylessness with $n=1$ and then gives $$E[X]=P(X=1)\times 1+P(X>1)(E[X]+1) = 1+P(X>1)E[X]$$ which again gives  $E=1 + \frac12E$ when $P(X>1)=\frac12$.

Nic's answer is a generalisation of this, using $p_H$ and $1-p_H$ instead of $\frac12$.
